# powershell Сортировка Group-object

Tags: powershell

Уважаемые профессионалы, допустим я отсортировал таблицу по определенным столбцам, через Group (всего нужно было задействовать два столбца). У меня таблица состоит из 8 полей (столбцов). И задействовав Group я вынужден потом обращаться к каждому полю что бы потом получить первоначальный вид из всех столбцов с их правильными именами.

$arr |Group ИмяКомпьютера | Select @{n="ИмяКомпьютера";e={$*.Values }},           @{n="ДатаВхода";e={$*.Group.ДатаВхода | Get-Date  | Sort | Select -Last  1}}

Далее я должен перечислить оставшиеся 6 полей, с которыми я вообще ничего не делал, через обращение в группу: ИмяПользователя, IPАдрес, Телефон и т.д..

Как можно сократить код, что бы не перечислять всё это в массиве группы? Или так уже не получится? Сортировка вещь прекрасная, но "выйти из группы" потом это тоже нелегкая задача получается.

$arr у меня, как вы поняли, это объекты со значениями, имена которых: ИмяКомпьютера, ДатаВхода, IPАдрес, Телефон, Должность...

Comment: это русский stackoverflow, сообщения на другом языке запрещены

Answer (score 0):

Первый и самый лаконичный вариант:

```
$arr| group ИмяКомпьютера | foreach { $_.group | sort ДатаВхода -descending | select -first 1} |FT
```

Второй вариант:

```
$arr |Group ИмяКомпьютера |  Foreach {
    $i = $_.Group[0]
    $i.ДатаВхода = $_.Group.ДатаВхода | Get-Date | Sort | Select -Last 1
    $i
} | ft
```